# How do I scrape "Contact Info" from facebook public page?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want to scrape contact info from some facebook public pages like phone, email, website, etc, which are listed bellow the "Contact Info" heading in the About section of the any facebook page.

I am using SIMPLE_HTML_DOM parser for scraping.

The problem is when I am using the function, `echo $html = file_get_html($url);` it does not display anything.

Also, when I use curl e.g. `echo $html=str_get_html($myUrl);` it is displaying the html for me also having some http path info text at the top of the page but when I see the source of this page it contains json code having the `<h4>contact info</h4>` in some html commented code.

Now when I target the div containing `<h4>` and other info  bellow, 
like, `$Contact_info = $html->find('div #pagelet_contact_info')->plaintext;`
it doesn't return anything for me and give me the notice,

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\scoopon_deals\test.php on line 18

Because it does not find the specific div the html returned which I called for, I tried it for even every tag in the page and for href's etc but doesn't find.
....

My Code is following!

include('connect.php');
include('simple_html_dom.php');

```
 $url = "http://www.facebook.com/ScooponTravel/info";
         $myUrl =curl_grab($url,"https://www.google.com", "", "false",  "null", "false");

          echo $html=str_get_html($myUrl);

        //echo $html = file_get_html($url);

        if(is_object($html)){

            echo "helloooo";echo '<br>';


            $Contact_info = $html->find('div #pagelet_contact_info')->plaintext;

                //print_r($deal_title);


            echo "Yesss";

        }


    ////// curl function
function curl_grab($url,$ref_url,$data,$login,$proxy,$proxystatus){

        if($login == 'true') {
           if($fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w")){
            fclose($fp);
        }else{echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";}
            }
        // global $charam;

     $charam = curl_init();
     //curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
      //curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        //curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        //curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        //curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 440);
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        if ($proxystatus == 'true') {
            curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        }
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);

        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
     //   curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    // curl_setopt($charam, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        //ob_start();
     $curl_result =  curl_exec ($charam);
     //curl_close ($charam);
     return $curl_result;
        //ob_end_clean();
        //curl_close ($charam);
        //unset($charam);
```

}

Comment: Facebook has an API. Use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook Graph API to get the Contact Details:

```
<?php
$file=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/ScooponTravel");
$json=json_decode($file);
echo $json->website;
```

This returns http://www.scoopon.com.au/travel

Comment: @ Capt.Nemo, Thanks al0ooottt... It worked fine for me.

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct (click the green tick button next to it).